# app.config creating and reading sections trouble

Tags: .net, app-config

I have been trying to work with app.config sections by this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationcollectionattribute.aspx#Y2391

and its giving me the next exception:

`An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for MyUrls:
Could not load file or assembly 'ConfigurationCollectionAttribute, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (E:\Projects\AppConfigSectionsTesting\AppConfigSectionsTesting\bin\Debug\AppConfigSectionsTesting.vshost.exe.Config line 4)`

this is the config file -

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

 <configSections>
   <section name="MyFolders" type="FoldersSection, 
      ConfigurationCollectionAttribute, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=null" />
</configSections>
<MyFolders>
   <Folders>
    <add Path ="D:\\RUN"/>
</Folders>
</MyFolders>

 </configuration>
```

i dont understand why.... can anyone help?
thank you.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the relevant bits of your `app.config` please?  (or post the whole thing)

Comment: clearly the file/assembly: ConfigurationCollectionAttribute is not available at runtime so the error, make sure the assembly is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app.config, check that you've got the full namespace to the class `ConfigurationCollectionAttribute`

For example:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="configSectionName"
             type="Company.Namespace.ConfigSection, Company.Namespace" />
</configSections>
```